# How can I serialize this Json using my model class?

Tags: c#, api, serialization

I have having a problem how to get the empty list and define the properties and set the values in a static method.

FYI : I am also using the same properties id and parentID in another payload that is not a List..

```
//Here is the json I have
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "parentId": 4
  }
]


//Here is my model class, my static method "Payload" and the properties of Json


public class Model
{

   public int id { get; set; }
   public int parentId { get; set; }


       public static Model Payload()
        {
              return new Model 
               {
                    //How to get define the List here and set the values

               }

        }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The json you have is a List so, with [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/), you can deserialize to a list.

`var myModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(jsonString);`

If the json string is empty "[]", it will create an empty list (not sure if that's what you were asking about the empty list of Model).

To convert the list to string:

`var stringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myModels);`

Comment: yes i am aware of the deserialize and serialize but.. how to set the values I have in a list like how its coming in the Json. After I can do this.. I will use the Serialize method to pass in my API call.. but I first need to know how to set its values in the list

Comment: Are you saying that you don't know what properties might be in the JSON? That you will need to know. You can Deserialize to an anonymous type but even with that, you need to know the properties ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

What is your goal exactly ? You just want to load a model from a JSON string ? If not, what is this list exactly ? I think you should look at this : https://www.newtonsoft.com/json
It's a very popular library for manipulate JSON and data model related to it.

Comment: i am trying to set the values in a list like how its in the Json.